# DirectXTK 3D audio uses only left channel

Tags: directx, directx-12, xaudio2, directxtk

I've decided to try the DirectXTK12 audio and it's working fine except for the 3D sound. I'm following the [guide from wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Audio) but the sound is always in the left speaker no matter how I position the listener/emitter. What's wrong? My code looks like this:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
if (FAILED(hr)) {...}

std::unique_ptr<DirectX::AudioEngine> audEngine;

DirectX::AUDIO_ENGINE_FLAGS eflags = DirectX::AudioEngine_Default;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    eflags |= DirectX::AudioEngine_Debug;
#endif

std::unique_ptr<DirectX::SoundEffect> soundEffect;
soundEffect = std::make_unique<DirectX::SoundEffect>(audEngine.get(), L"Sound.wav");
auto effect = soundEffect->CreateInstance(DirectX::SoundEffectInstance_Use3D);

effect->Play(false);

DirectX::AudioListener listener;
listener.SetPosition(DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

DirectX::AudioEmitter emitter;
emitter.SetPosition(DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

effect->Apply3D(listener, emitter, false);
```

It should be in the center but it's only using the left channel although there are no errors in the output, the only thing the output says is this:

```
INFO: XAudio 2.9 debugging enabled
INFO: mastering voice has 2 channels, 96000 sample rate, 00000003 channel mask
```

Playing the sound without 3D uses both speakers as expected.

Comment: With both emitter and listener at the same point, I'm not sure you are getting a valid test. What happens if you move the emitter left or right? Also you should probably dump the details about ``Sound.wav`` into the question. You can do it with this utility [wavdump.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wavdump.cpp). Also, check your audio device in the Windows control panel to make sure both left & right are working properly and that you have the Stereo speaker type set.

Comment: Note that the math breaks down if you have both listener and emitter at exactly the same spot, so don't trust that as a test.  Also, XAudio2 is multithreaded so you need to enter a loop somewhere to wait for the sound to play on the worker thread.  See [this tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Using-positional-audio) for a full walkthrough of using positional audio via *DirectX Tool Kit for DX11*.

Comment: Another note, if your ``Sound.wav`` file has more than 1 channel, you need to add: ``emitter.ChannelCount = soundEffect->GetFormat()->nChannels;``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by converting used Sound.wav to mono (1 channel) sound.

Comment: The problem was a mis-configured multi-channel sound. The fix was to use a mono wav file -or- to set ``emitter.ChannelCount`` and ``emitter.EmitterAzimuths`` to sensible values for the stereo sound per [GameFest 2010: The (3D) Sound of Success: X3DAudio and Sound Positioning](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17627).